# Minimizing computation time

Tags: mathematical-optimization, computational-complexity

I'm having issues with reducing the computation time of a NMinimize function. I've tried setting the `WorkingPrecision` and `N` and adding constraints to the variable in `NMinimize` but more or less the computation time is way too long.

```
ClearAll["`*"]
$Assumptions = {HeavisideTheta[0] == 1, HeavisideTheta[0.] == 1, 
  0 < j1 <= 5, 0 < j2 <= 5, 0 < j3 <= 5, 0 < j4 <= 5, 0 < t1, 
  t1 <= t2, t2 <= t3, t3 <= t4, t4 <= t5, t5 <= t6, t6 <= t7}
eps = 0.05
wn = 2 Pi 5

func[q_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{vmax, sol, j, a, v, x, constraint1, constraint2, constraint3,
    t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, yofs, yoft, j1, j2, j3, j4, temp500},

  j[t_] = 
   j1 (UnitStep[t] - UnitStep[t - t1]) - 
    j2 (UnitStep[t - t2] - UnitStep[t - t3]) - 
    j3 (UnitStep[t - t4] - UnitStep[t - t5]) + 
    j4 (UnitStep[t - t6] - UnitStep[t - t7]);
  a[t_] = Integrate[j[t], t];
  v[t_] = Integrate[a[t], t];
  x[t_] = Integrate[v[t], t];
  constraint1 = 
   FullSimplify[
    a[t7], {0 < j1 <= 5, 0 < j2 <= 5, 0 < j3 <= 5, 0 < j4 <= 5, 
     0 < t1, t1 <= t2, t2 <= t3, t3 <= t4, t4 <= t5, t5 <= t6, 
     t6 <= t7}];
  constraint2 = 
   FullSimplify[
    v[t7], {0 < j1 <= 5, 0 < j2 <= 5, 0 < j3 <= 5, 0 < j4 <= 5, 
     0 < t1, t1 <= t2, t2 <= t3, t3 <= t4, t4 <= t5, t5 <= t6, 
     t6 <= t7}];
  constraint3 = 
   FullSimplify[
    x[t7], {0 < j1 <= 5, 0 < j2 <= 5, 0 < j3 <= 5, 0 < j4 <= 5, 
     0 < t1, t1 <= t2, t2 <= t3, t3 <= t4, t4 <= t5, t5 <= t6, 
     t6 <= t7}];
  vmax = (j1 t1 t1 + (t3 - t2) j1 t1)/2 + (t2 - t1) j1 t1; 
  sol = NMinimize[{t7, {t1 j1 - j2 (t3 - t2) == 0, 
      j1 t1 <= 0.7, -j3 (t5 - t4) >= -0.7, 
      j1 t1 (t2 + t3 - t1)/2 <= 0.14, constraint1 == 0, 
      constraint2 == 0, constraint3 == 0.05, 0 < j1 <= 5, 0 < j2 <= 5,
       0 < j3 <= 5, 0 < j4 <= 5, 0 < t1, t1 <= t2, t2 <= t3, t3 <= t4,
       t4 <= t5, t5 <= t6, t6 <= t7, t7 < 2}}, {j1, j2, j3, j4, t1, 
     t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7}];
  {j1, j2, j3, j4, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, 
    t7} = {j1, j2, j3, j4, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7} /. sol[[2]];
  Clear[j3, j4, t5, t6, t7, t4];
  j3 = q;
  j4 = q;
  {t4, t5, t6, t7} = {t4, t5, t6, t7} /. 
    NMinimize[{t7, {constraint1 == 0, constraint2 == 0, 
        constraint3 == 0.05, -j3 (t5 - t4) >= -0.7, t5 > t4, t6 >= t5,
         t7 > t6, t4 >= t3}}, {t4, t5, t6, t7}][[2]];
   yofs = -LaplaceTransform[a[t], t, s]/(s^2 + 2 eps wn s + wn^2);
  yoft = InverseLaplaceTransform[yofs, s, t];
  NMinimize[{N[Re[FullSimplify[yoft, t > t7]]], t > t7, t < 1.5 t7}, 
    t, WorkingPrecision -> 9][[1]]
(*Column[{NMinimize[{Re[FullSimplify[yoft, t > t7]], t > t7}, t][[1]], 
  Plot[Re[yoft], {t, t7, 1.5 t7}]}*)]

  ]
(*func[3]
  func[4]
*)
DiscretePlot[func[q], {q, 3, 5, 0.01}]
```

When I make the output of the function as the one in comment and call 2 individual functions the results are what I want(takes around 3 minutes to compute 2 outputs) but when I run a discrete plot, 200 calls, basically would take 5 hours which is too much. is there a way to reduce this. Using `N` or using constraints or using `WorkingPrecision` isn't changing the computation time either.

Comment: For starters, have you tried either pre-calculating the simplified versions of your constraints, or just simply removing all the calls to `FullSimplify` throughout? Those can be time-consuming and may not make much sense within `f` once numerical values are introduced.

Comment: Also, why does your code assign values to some variables (eg `j3, j4, t5, t6, t7, t4`) and then immediately `Clear` them in the very next line of code?

Comment: @MarcoB I start with the time optimized solution for the parameters, the first minimize and then make some variables free and the see how the solution works when I vary the freed vars. Also that part isn't whats slowing the code down as the result for code upto time optimzed solution is pretty quick

Comment: I would recommend that you try to carry out as many of the symbolic manipulations OUTSIDE of f as possible. For instance, the indefinite integration to generate $a, v, t$ could be carried out outside of the function symbolically, so you avoid doing them every time your function is called. But your real bottlenecks will still be the horrendously complicated `NMinimize` calls with multiple difficult constraints. Those will be hard to speed up. This needs some symbolic manipulation beforehand to simplify your problem, if possible.

Comment: @MarcoB Well it helped, dropped down the computation time significantly, still took 10-15 minutes but not a big deal.pretty much computed a,v,x and yoft outside and plugged them in.